# How do Google/Android/iPhone recognize street addresses in emails and other text?

Tags: android, iphone, parsing, google-maps

They don't do it perfectly but pretty darn well. It's not an easy problem, how do they do it?

Comment: i realise this doesn't answer your question, but in case you're interested, this feature is available to devs on iOS via NSDataDetector (http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not obviously for street addresses, I don't know about the other platforms, but iOS has a property of UITextView:

```
 textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Which will detect emails, phone numbers and URL's in the text, static or loaded. It will highlight the detected data to allow you to act on it in the app. It might work for streets if they are in the form of a Google Map URL?